# (esp-idf) why cannot subscribe "$aws" topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, esp32, aws-iot, esp-idf

i'm testing aws iot example code with esp32 and esp-idf

Using example below,
https://github.com/espressif/esp-aws-iot/tree/master/examples/mqtt/tls_mutual_auth

It works well with normal topic(ex."esp/test/topic").
But It doesn't work with reserved topic(ex. "$aws/certificates/create/json/accepted")

**example code show succeed to subscribe log,
But i can't receive any message from reserved topic.**

To provisioning i have to subscribe reserved topic below

- $aws/certificates/create/json/accepted
- $aws/certificates/create/json/rejected
- $aws/provisioning-templates/{template name}/provision/json/accepted
- $aws/provisioning-templates/{template name}/provision/json/rejected

But i can't get any message from these topic.

why it doesn't work?

thanks for your help

Comment: https://repost.aws/questions/QU09EItn9DQYKaw_E5Pqb6hA/aws-iot-fleet-provisioning-doesn-t-publish-certificate-response
Would that help?